# add uml plugin to netbeans 6.9.1 in mac os

Tags: netbeans, uml, netbeans-6.9

i have a java project maked with netbeans . I want to get UML diagram from this project .I founded this plugin http://blogs.oracle.com/JavaFundamentals/entry/generating_uml_from_the_netbeans but i can't find it in netbans upgrade tool  . Can you help me please ? i use netbeans 6.9.1 and mac os x 10.6.7

Comment: Check for an answer to your question here http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=netbeans+uml+support

Answer (score 0):

The UML Plugin was supported only until NetBeans 6.7.1